# property list value as \url argument

Tags: urls, l3prop

I want to feed `\url` with the value of a property list

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_tmpa_prop {
  mail=user@domain,
}
\prop_get:NnN \l_tmpa_prop { mail } \l_tmpa_tl
\url{\l_tmpa_tl}
\end{document}
```

What I get is `\unhbox\voidb@x\bgroup\@xxxiil\egroup_tmpa_tl`.
How can I obtain `user@domain` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to pass the value to `\url`, not the variable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_tmpa_prop {
  mail=user@domain,
}
\prop_get:NnN \l_tmpa_prop { mail } \l_tmpa_tl
\exp_args:NV \url \l_tmpa_tl

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Here `\exp_args:NV` jumps over the first token because of `N` and provides the `V`alue of the variable enclosed in braces.

Answer (score 1):

You have to expand `\l_tmpa_tl`, which I accomplish with `\expandafter\url\expandafter{\l_tmpa_tl}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_tmpa_prop {
  mail=user@domain,
}
\prop_get:NnN \l_tmpa_prop { mail } \l_tmpa_tl
\expandafter\url\expandafter{\l_tmpa_tl}
\end{document}
```

[image]